# Always overwrite a git deployment branch

Tags: git, github, merge, repository

We work with front-end code, e.g. HTML, CSS, JS etc

We have a preview branch (`qa`) on Github that, when pushed to, automatically deploys the code to a preview website for our QA team to test.

We compile / build our code into a `dist` directory and this is served on the preview website. Of course, typically the `dist` directory would be ignored.

**How can we push our development branches and always overwrite our preview branch?**

We want to ignore any conflicts and **always** use the new code we are pushing. The code in the preview branch should never seep back into the development branches. We never ever work on code directly in the preview branch.

#### Context

We are a small, but geographically distributed team and we work on large front-end projects with several release waves. There is no *production* as such because our work is supplied to other teams who manage integration with internal CMS systems etc.

The `master` branch represents the last release. Typically we will work sequentially, i.e. work on `wave1` and release to `master`, work on `wave2` and release to `master` and so on. However sometimes we will need to apply a hotfix to `wave1` while we are working on `wave2`. The fix in `wave1` will need to be temporarily deployed to `qa` for testing.

We create feature branches and use Pull Requests to merge them into the current wave branch.

Currently we use this strategy to deploy the current wave to `qa`:

```
git push origin wave2:qa
```

However this often results in a conflict in the `dist` directory, in which case we do this:

1. `git checkout qa` (checkout the `qa` branch locally)
2. `git pull` (make sure it is up to date)
3. `git checkout wave2` (switch back to wave branch)
4. `git merge -s ours qa` (merge `qa` branch in, using the ours strategy)
5. `git checkout qa` (switch back to `qa`)
6. `git merge wave2` (merge `wave2` in)
7. `git push` (push to deploy)

Now I've noticed that this really screws with our commit history and if we ever need to deploy an older wave to `qa` for a hotfix test we can end up with commits (and code a couple of times) in our `wave1` branch that should only be in our `wave2` branch.

It all feels a bit wrong to me, but I'm not sure what the best solution is here. I think perhaps we're trying to fit a square peg into a round hole using this ours strategy.

Should we be using `git push origin wave2:qa --force` instead?

Or perhaps we should have a different remote for the preview branch?

Or maybe the build step should happen on the server so that the `dist` directory isn't in the repo?

Happy to work outside our current strategy here as we'd like to move to a more strict `git flow` model anyway.

All we really need is a technique that allows us to easily deploy our work to a preview site without encountering conflict issues or cross-contamination of branches / releases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can we push our development branches and always overwrite our preview branch?
>
> Should we be using git push origin wave2:qa --force instead?

```
git push -f ...
```

The -f (--force) is for force push. It will overwrite the current content of your remote branch. You just have to verify that you have the permissions of doing so.